# thymeleaf spring boot OneToMany

Tags: spring-boot, templates, jpa, thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

Is there any possibility to add in parent template (OneToMany), some childs (ManyToOne) and in the same page please?
Thank you in advance

[image: Description Here]

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65173002/creating-arraylist-from-thymelaf-form-input-values ? That question might help you get started on implementing this.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but this is referring to spring boot. Have you seen a concreet sample of using or editing child item with method post save please ?